# How to mask a not rendered field in JSF?

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, primefaces, mask

The thing is I want to know how to mask a field, that is not rendered when I load the page.
For example: I have an h:inputText that only renders after the user do something.

If the input text is rendered=true when I load the page, its working fine, but I need the user to hit a button, and based on a condition, the application renders the inputText or not.

Here is jQuery code:

```
$('input[name*="preco"]').maskMoney({symbol:"R$",decimal:".",thousands:","});
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either just render the script conditionally as well:

```
<h:inputText ... rendered="#{some condition}" />
<h:outputScript rendered="#{some condition}">maskMoney()</h:outputScript>
```

or, if you're using a PrimeFaces command component, make use of PrimeFaces `oncomplete`:

```
<p:commandButton ... oncomplete="maskMoney()" />
```

or, if you're using `<f:ajax>`, make use of `onevent`:

```
<f:ajax ... onevent="function(data) { if (data.status == 'success') maskMoney() }" />
```

Comment: Thanks man. I'm new here, and I didn't notice the you have answered my question (I was expecting an email), that's why it took so long for me to vote the answer. Anyway, thanks a lot.